# how to input multiple vectors to DNN?

Tags: python

**I am trying to build a fake news detector using cosine similarity and tfidf with a Dense Neural Network. The dataset is as:

[image: Dataset]

**Code :**

```
'''DNN model'''
def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=1 , activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=20, batch_size=5, verbose=0

# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/shiva/Desktop/merodata1.csv")
dataframe.head()
dataset = dataframe.values

X =  dataset[0:,1:3]
Y = dataset[0:,4]

#one hot encoding
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

#Kfold for validation
kf = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("Train Index: ", train_index, "\n")
    print("Test Index: ", test_index)

#Results for each fold
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kf)
```

**But I am suffering with this error:**

```
#ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_9_input to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

**Can any one help me out of this problem?**

Comment: Paste your code, not image of if please

Comment: Can you describe what the error is? What line is causing an issue? Is the model not training or achieving bad results?

Comment: I have created a .csv file that consists of  tfidf of news title and news body in vector representation. But I am not being able to feed these vectors to the neural network for detecting fake or real news.